# How to get all share apps installed on the device?

Tags: android

i want to get share text and image, i find application package wise search then share application wise share functionality.

please help.

NOTE: i just want to share text with links nothing more.

thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Intent intentIN = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("PACKAGE NAME");
         if (intentIN != null) {
             Intent shareIntentIN = new Intent();
             shareIntentIN.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
             shareIntentIN.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
             try {
              shareIntentIN.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), "", "I am Happy", "Share happy !")));
             } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
             shareIntentIN.setType("image/jpeg");

             startActivity(shareIntentIN);
         } else {
             // bring user to the market to download the app.
             // or let them choose an app?
          intentIN = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
          intentIN.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          intentIN.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.instagram.android&hl=en"));
             startActivity(intentIN);
         }
```

please try this.change package name as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mUrl);
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mTitle);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share XXX"));
```